# Item alignment within an image carousel

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, slider

I'm using the [Owl Carousel responsive slider](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/), and I'm trying to figure out how to position image and caption elements within the main container. I have a test page set up [**here**](http://goo.gl/dK1xj7) and I'm attaching a mockup guide. Ideally, I'd like to set up a max/min-height for the container element, fix the `<p>` caption to the bottom left of the container, and vertically align the image to the middle of the slider.

Is this possible via basic CSS? Thanks for any guidance here.

[image: position image and caption within slider container]

Answer (score 6):

Add this to your css file:

```
div.owl-item > div {
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

and add this to your JS file (or between the head tag) for dynamic w/h:

```
$(window).load(function() {

var maxH = 0;
var maxW = 0;
$('img','div.owl-item > div').each(function(f) {
if ($(this).height() > maxH) { maxH = $(this).height() };
if ($(this).width() > maxW) { maxW = $(this).width() };
});
$('div.owl-item > div')
.height(maxH)
.width(maxW);


});
```

Comment: that works very well, thanks-- the only issue however, is I'd prefer to not specify a static height since the page is to be responsive; is there a way to modify the positioning in the JS to factor in the dynamic width/height?

Comment: here I've edited my answer. please accept is as answer if it's ok for you.

Comment: this is very helpful-- thanks. I'm still having an issue with differently oriented images, though. I've updated my link above, and you'll see in the 4th slide, I have a vertically-oriented image that is pushing the entire slider down because stretching its width to 100% is forcing it's height to expand. I'm wondering how to fit both tall and wide images and have them aligned horizontally and vertically in the fixed-aspect ratio container if that makes sense...

Comment: I think it's happening becuase the code is executing before the images loading. To correct this, just change "$(document).ready" with "$(window).load" I've updated my answer, I think this should do what you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

If you want dynamic height of image for responsive, set it's height with jquery.

#### DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/nLJ79/

`note:` after resize the result frame, hit 'run' button again.

#### JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#owl").owlCarousel({
        navigation: true,
        singleItem: true
    });
    $('.owl-pagination .owl-page, .owl-buttons div').on('click',function(){
        $('.owl-item div').css('height',$('.owl-item div').css('height'));
    });
});
```